# Very wrong answers

Tags: discussion, flagging, halacha

I noticed recently some users who posted a lot of very wrong answers. I'm thinking to myself that, on one side we are not a site of psak, and the damage is only intellectual. Moreover if this user writes with *cheshek* and will learn a lot, it's fine. I don't love to fight people that learn with *cheshek*.

On the other hand, I don't like a public *amaratsut*, particularly with very wrong answers spreading.

What do people think is the right guideline?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4637/170

Comment: I think there is an important difference between someone who is wrong but agrees to be corrected, and someone who is wrong, gets downvoted multiple times, and keeps the answer on the site for others to see and learn the wrong answer. I have no issue with the first one, we are all here to learn, but have real difficulties with the second approach. When I can I try to provide an alternative answer and leave comments showing where I see issues with the "wrong" answer

Comment: Downvotes are important here.  If somebody visits the site and sees an answer that most of us know is wrong (the visitor doesn't know, hence looking for an answer) and that answer has a negative score, that tells the viewer something.  At -3 answers are grayed out, which is further signal.  Yes, of course we should try to work with the author to correct errors -- and remove those downvotes when that happens -- but I'm just saying that there *is* a way to signal "this is wrong", and everybody with at least 125 rep has the ability to contribute to that signal.

Comment: If an answer falls into the "very wrong" category, and the poster is a repeat offender, there is always the option of flagging it for moderator attention.

Comment: Why offender. To be wrong is more frequent than to be right. @shmu

Comment: Then you are in the minority, @kouty :)

Comment: Not sure @shmu.

Comment: I meant it like this: if the majority are wrong, then you are in the minority, because you are right. lol. joke. pardon my convoluted logic...